# How to keep the desired letter and hide the other characters with "*"? Is there a simpler and efficient way?

Tags: java

I want to keep the desired letter that the user inputs using the scanner and hide all the other characters with a "*", how would I do that with a for loop or substring? I managed to do it with a for loop for one letter the user inputs, but In total, this needs to happen with 5 different letters the user inputs using a scanner.

```
Sample input: 4(option #), dog(mysteryphrase), o(letter)
Sample output: *o*
```

This needs to happen with 5 letters, how would I do that?

This was my attempt:

```
          else if (option == 4){
                int counter = 1;
                int counter2 = 0;
                boolean go = true;
                char letter = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                String r1 = "";
                for (int y = 0; y < mysteryphrase.length(); y++){
                    char n1 = mysteryphrase.charAt(y);
                    if (n1 == letter)
                    r1+=n1;
                    else
                    r1+="*";
                }
                System.out.println(r1);
                char letter2 = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                String r2 = "";
                for (int x = 0; x < mysteryphrase.length(); x++){
                    char n2 = mysteryphrase.charAt(x);
                    if (n2 == letter2)
                    r2+=n2;
                    else
                    r2+="*";
                }
                System.out.println(r2);
                char letter3 = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                String r3 = "";
                for (int w = 0; w < mysteryphrase.length(); w++){
                    char n3 = mysteryphrase.charAt(w);
                    if (n3 == letter3)
                    r3+=n3;
                    else
                    r3+="*";
                }
                System.out.println(r3);
                char letter4 = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                String r4 = "";
                for (int z = 0; z < mysteryphrase.length(); z++){
                    char n4 = mysteryphrase.charAt(z);
                    if (n4 == letter4)
                    r4+=n4;
                    else
                    r4+="*";
                }
                System.out.println(r4);
                char letter5 = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                String r5 = "";
                for (int s = 0; s < mysteryphrase.length(); s++){
                    char n5 = mysteryphrase.charAt(s);
                    if (n5 == letter5)
                    r5+=n5;
                    else
                    r5+="*";
```

Although I managed to hide the letters with a "*", one another requirement is:
And whenever the letter is not in the word, let's say:

```
Sample input: 4, dog, z
```

Then it should output:

```
Sample output: Z is not in the word
```

This is where I'm stuck, can you please help? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61643733/2970947

Comment: There is no answer there

Comment: `r1 = mysteryphrase.replaceAll("[^" + letter + "]", "*");`.

Comment: I cant use replaceall, only loops or substring

Comment: Why do you need to repeat the same code 5 times?

Comment: I couldnt find another way

Answer (score 1):

Try this **updated version**:

```
String letters = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    letters += keyboard.next().charAt(0) + ", ";
}

String r = "";
boolean found = false;
for (int y = 0; y < mysteryphrase.length(); y++) {
    char n = mysteryphrase.charAt(y);
    if (letters.indexOf(n) > -1) {
        r += n;
        found = true;
    } else {
        r += "*";
    }
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("Letters " + letters + " not in the word");
} else {
    System.out.println(r);
}
```

Output for input `a b c d e` and `mysteryphrase = "acknowledgement"`:

```
ac*****ed*e*e**
```

Output for input `q b z r s` and `mysteryphrase = "acknowledgement"`:

```
Letters q,b,z,r,s not in the word
```

Or, if you have to do this task separately for each letter (not for all five ones together), you can extract a single method and call it 5 times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    char letter = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    String r = "";
    boolean found = false;
    for (int j = 0, n = mysteryphrase.length(); j < n; j++) {
        char c = mysteryphrase.charAt(0);
        if (c == letter) {
            r += c;
            found = true;
        } else {
            r += '*';
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("Letter " + letter + " not in the word");
    } else {
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Letter b not in the word
******l*****
a***********
*c**********
**k*********
```

Comment: I cant use arrays

Comment: And yes, i need it for a different letter

Comment: For what letter?

Comment: What do you mean you can't use arrays?  Java Strings are backed internally by a char array too.

Comment: I cannot use any library other than scanner, and only substring or loop method

Comment: Please tell me which _library other than scanner_ you see in my answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Whats "sb" there is no variable of that name

Comment: it should be `r`, `sb` remained from previous edit - though it's better to use `StringBuilder` instead of string concatenation operator `+` in such case.

Comment: Please accept my answer if you used code from here in your [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61666599/how-do-i-add-a-symbol-that-changes-after-each-user-input-java).  Thank you.